# how to debug in iOS5

Tags: xcode, ios5

i put the break points at some lines in my app, when i run the app it is not debugging i.e my application is not stopping at breakpoints...

can any one please tell me how to enable debugging in iOS5

Comment: restart xcode and application. Hope it might solve

Answer (score 0):

Show breakpoint navigator -> Add exception breakpoint -> Done

Comment: He says it's not stopping, not that it stops where he set no break points.